# ASP.NET MVC How to add line break

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got the following code in my asp.net mvc VIEW.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <span id="errorId" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: #FF0004;"></span> @Model.ErrorMessage
   </div>
</div>
```

The `@Model.ErrorMessage` may contain contain multiple strings but when the View is rendered, I don't see the line break. I tried adding `<br />` and `\r\n` but its all rendered on 1 line.

Here is a sample of the returning error message:

> The first field is required.\r\nThe second field is required.\r\nThe third field is required.\r\n

I replaced the `\r\n` with `<br>` line tag but it still does not work.

how can I break the string up into separate lines? Thanks.

Comment: In normal situations, `\r\n` won't get you a new line in an HTML page. The equivalent would be a `<br />` tag, though that's falling out of favor.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `@Model.ErrorMessage` in `<pre> </pre>` tags

Answer (score 1):

HTML Linebreak? `<br />` ?
But it depends on your HTML if `<br />` is the best, or `<p>` or a list `<ul>`.

If u want to split on `\r\n` then use `String.Split()` Method and you'll get an `string[]` which you can use to iterate and build your HTML list.

But all depends more or less on your HTML code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.